# Neo4j - Recursive query with relationship weights

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am building a tool that enables users to recommend sequences of online courses to other users.

Off the back of the data generated from that, I would like to generate insights on what the most recommended sequences of courses are. Here's a slice of the model:

[image]

In this graph, the numbers in green are weights that show how many people have recommended one course after the other (ex: 655 people recommend taking Stanford's ML after Intro to Prob)

The `recs` field in nodes is the absolute number of recommendations that course has (ex: Stanford ML has been featured by 1000 users in sequences)

What I would like to do, is starting from an end goal, finding out the most recommended pre-requisites.

The algorithm might work something like this:

```
Function fancy_algo (node, graph)
    If (no prereqs OR prereq weight is very low)
        Return graph
    Get all incoming nodes
    For each incoming node subject
        MR = most recommended pre-req
        Append MR to graph
        fancy_algo(MR, graph)
```

The end state for someone looking to do Stanford's Machine Learning might look something like this:

[image]

Note how after "Intro to CS" we haven't included "Algebra", because its prereq weight was very low (20 out of 4567).

Is this something that can be managed with Cypher? How would I get started?

Comment: In your bottom diagram, why did you pick "Intro to Prob" instead of "Princeton Algs", which has more recommendations on the relationship? More importantly, you probably cannot just use the recommendation counts as-is when going backwards -- you probably need to use something like [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) to generate the actual probability that a particular path is the best. Your technique is only statistically valid if the probability of taking every courses is identical.

Comment: Because I pick the most recommended one by category. Note how "Intro to Prob" belongs to probability, "Stanford Algos" is algorithms; the other two category duplicates are discarded on the basis that they are less popular.

Why would I need Bayes in this context? The algorithm picks the most recommended course per category in absolute terms, period. It's unsophisticated, but it's a first approximation. I think one of the things that contributes to the confusion is that the recommendation figures on the vertices and on the edges are wrong - I'm going to edit that.

Comment: Sorry, the figures are not wrong - got confused there for a minute.

Comment: The results would be truly "unsophisticated", as you said, and may be a poor approximation. Suppose 100K people take course A and 1K of them recommend course C, and suppose 500 people take course B and 400 of them recommend course C. When going backwards from C, shouldn't you pick course B instead of A?

Comment: Yes, actually this is a good point. It would suffice to see which one has the best relative recommendation weight per category, so in your example it would be 80% vs 1%, which is a dead-easy decision. One thing which I did mention is there will be a threshold under which prereqs won't be considered (ex: under 30%) - but above that threshold, it makes sense to measure in relative terms, not absolute.